# Django: Why is console email backend not sending emails?

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to make an app to reset user password via email. I'm using the Django by Example book chapter 3, and also took guidance from this site: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/09/19/how-to-create-password-reset-view.html

Settings.py contains the following line:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

together with the required email settings.

I get to the `password_reset` view, enter dummy mail, click send, which finally brings me to the `password_reset_done` view. Below is the console output:

```
C:\PythonProjects\by-example-bookmarks>python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 01, 2018 - 21:13:39
Django version 2.0.4, using settings 'bookmarks.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[01/May/2018 21:13:51] "GET /account/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1090
[01/May/2018 21:13:57] "GET /account/password_reset/ HTTP/1.1" 200 830
[01/May/2018 21:14:04] "POST /account/password_reset/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[01/May/2018 21:14:05] "GET /account/password_reset/done/ HTTP/1.1" 200 602
```

After the `"POST"` output I expect to see a dump of the email in response to `.console.EmailBackend` setting, but got nothing, ever.

What could be the cause of the failure to simulate sending email?

Environment:

Windows 7, django 2.0, on CMD console, under pipenv shell

**Edit 1**
Same problem on a different machine.

**Edit 2**
Changing to `.smtp` doesn't change anything, no error.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

**Edit 3**
I tried other people's work, like this one: https://github.com/ruddra/django-reset-password/tree/master

Still no luck.

**Edit 4**
Yet another "other people's work". Still no luck. https://github.com/wsvincent/django-auth-tutorial

Does it ever work?

**Edit 5: views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from .forms import LoginForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate( username=cd['username'],
                                 password=cd['password'])
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponse('Authenticated '\
                                        'successfully')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Disabled account')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request,
                  'account/dashboard.html',
                  {'section': 'dashboard'})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views
import django.contrib.auth.views
# i think the following does not serve any purpose anymore
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    # previous login view
    # url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login'),

    # login / logout urls
    url(r'^login/$',
        django.contrib.auth.views.login,
        name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$',
        django.contrib.auth.views.logout,
        name='logout'),
    url(r'^logout-then-login/$',
        django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login,
        name='logout_then_login'),
    url(r'^$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^password-change/$',
        django.contrib.auth.views.password_change,
        name='password_change'),
    url(r'^password-change/done/$',
        django.contrib.auth.views.password_change_done,
        name='password_change_done'),

    # restore password urls
    url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

**edit 6**
My github repo is here, in case anyone's curious: https://github.com/jeffplata/by-example-account

Comment: Can you post the view you are using?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, views.py included in edit. Not much to see there, actually. You might want to look at the `urls.py` though.

Comment: What version of django are you using?

Comment: @Burhan, django 2.0

Comment: Just curious - you did add a user, set it as active, and give it an email address, right? Have a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-a-password-reset-feature) as your `urls.py` doesn't match.

Comment: @Burhan yes I do have an active user with emaiil

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It works now. As suggested by @Burhan Khalid, made very very sure that the there is a user with a valid email. Specifically, the email I'm typing in the reset view is found in the Users model/table.

Comment: thanks dude, i was doing same wrong thing from past 2 weeks. Thanks for your ans.